# How to manage external Helm Chart dependencies

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm very curious how I should combine my own Helm chart with a set of contributed charts, i.e. the ones of BitNami.

So say I have my own chart that defines my backend application, how do I add a dependency to the contributed MySQL chart (instead of manually crafting it myself).

Another use case would be to add ArgoCD to my own custom chart. How do I do this in a declarative manner, without running the needed commands on the cluster manually?

I'm aware of the helm repo add and helm install for 3rd party charts, but these commands do not lend them well for CI/CD because they are not idempotent. I would like my chart to be declarative, so a single helm install also installs all listed dependencies. And the weird thing is that I cannot find anything about this topic online.

Would love your feedback!

Comment: Helm has a notion of [Chart Dependencies](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#chart-dependencies), so you can say that your application depends on a MySQL chart, at thus-and-such a URL, with this semver constraint, expected to deploy with this exact version.  Deploying the chart with the dependency listed in its `Chart.yaml` file would also deploy the dependency.  Does that functionality meet your needs?